# How can I add multiple tables in .NET 6 using Include command

Tags: c#, linq, .net-6.0, ef-core-3.1

I have 4 tables. How to join all tables and bind that data in model to pass to HTTPGET API.

I am using .NET6.

- `Employee` : PK empid; other columns: depid, payid
- `Department` : PK depid
- `PayGrade` : PK payId; other columns: locid
- `Location` : PK locid

I tried doing below but not able to add 4th table using include.

`_context` is my dbobject:

```
var result = _context.Employee
                     .Include(p => p.Department.depid)
                     .Include(p => p.PayGrade.payid)
                     // I want to include table Location i.e. 
                     // join it with table Paygrade based on locid a
                     // filter entire result for one employee
                     .Where(p => p.empid = @param)
```

Comment: What prevents you from doing that? Why can't you put another `Include` after the previous `Include`s?

Comment: when I added another include, I was getting error as my 4th table had no relation with my 1st table (primary table here).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the Location is dependend on the PayGrade you can include it this way:

```
var employees = _context.Employees
    .Include(e => e.Department)
    .Include(e => e.PayGrade)
        .ThenInclude(pg => pg.Location)
    .ToList();
```

If that does not work please provide further information about your models and the ef core configuration.

Comment: I created a  custom model (this model has fields from all the four tables). I want to bind result of above query to this custom model. Is it possible?

Comment: yes this should be possible. I recomment to create a new question where you show the models and the desired output.